# How to remove unnecessary field after grouping in rethinkdb, display just key-value pair?

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

I got some result like this in rethinkdb using **group**

```
[  
   {  
      "group":[  
         0,
         "A"
      ],
      "reduction":14
   },
   {  
      "group":[  
         "B",
         0
      ],
      "reduction":2
   }
]
```

I used like **r.....group(..).count()** (I cannot mentioned all query because there are many steps). But my result should like be displayed like this:

```
[  
       {  
          "group":[  
             "A"
          ],
          "reduction":14
       },
       {  
          "group":[  
             "B"
          ],
          "reduction":2
       }
    ]
```

Even Better just key value pair `[{"A":14},{"B":2}]`

Answer (score 1):

This is not the cleanest ReQL in the world, but it works!

```
r.expr([  
   {  
      "group":[  
         0,
         "A"
      ],
      "reduction":14
   },
   {  
      "group":[  
         "B",
         0
      ],
      "reduction":2
   }
])
.map(function (row) {
  // Return a tuple with the key and the value
  return [row('group').filter(function (row) { return row.eq(0).not() }).nth(0), row('reduction') ]
})
.map(function (row) {
  // Convert the tuple into an array by passing an array of key-value pairs
  return r.expr([row]).coerceTo('object')
})
```

You could combine these two  maps functions, but I personally think it's nicer to separate them out, in order to make them more understandable.

I used `r.expr` so you can just copy/paste it into the data explorer and see if it works, but you can just copy/paste the last two `maps`at the end of your query and the result would be the same.

Result:

```
[
  {
    "A": 14
  } ,
  {
    "B": 2
  }
]
```